# Notation of a Cobb-Douglas function printed in 1989

Tags: production-function, cobb-douglas

I am trying to understand a paper written back in 1989 about long run population growth. It seems like the PDF is a scanned image of the paper.

The notation for the function is on page 11 of the pdf ([here](http://faculty.econ.ucdavis.edu/faculty/gclark/papers/clark_evolution.pdf)):[image: Cobb-Douglas Function]

Is it:

$$ Q_t = A_t*(K_t^\alpha N^t_\beta T_t^\rho) $$

or

$$ Q_t = A_t*(K_t^\alpha N^\beta_t T_t^\rho) $$

Im not sure its a typo or not because it shows up the same way later in the paper on page 14.

*Edit:  I also have no idea what $\hat c$ is in the paper:

I don't see where it is defined.  Only where consumption is compared to it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be the second one, so $$ Q_t = A_t*(K_t^\alpha N^\beta_t T_t^\rho). $$

Two clues:

1. This is the usual specification.
2. On the top of page 14 it is written that
   $$
   w_t = \beta Q_t/N_t.
   $$ 
   Given a competitive labor market you have
   $$
   w_t = \frac{\partial Q_t}{\partial N_t}.
   $$ 
   If you assume the production function above then you indeed have
   $$
   \frac{\partial Q_t}{\partial N_t} = \beta Q_t/N_t.
   $$

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought it was bizarre but that maybe I was missing some special circumstance.